# Assigning values to Matlab structure of arbitrary nestedness

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a Matlab structure with varying depths, that is something like:

```
f.A = 1;
f.B.alpha = 20;
f.B.beta  = 30;
```

Now suppose you have a given input (say 'ctrl') that specifies a value to be reassigned, identifying the fieldname involved using a string. An example would be:

```
ctrl = {'B.alpha', 200};
```

Which means that we should re-assign f.B.alpha to 200. How would you implement this systematically, for a fieldname in ctrl having arbitrary 'depth' (or numbers of levels)? Speed would be nice, but is not an issue here.

Ultimately I'd like to apply a series of reassignments, for example as in:

```
ctrl = {'B.alpha', 200; 
        'A', -10};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have a quick and dirty solution, that can be expanded for a general solution:

```
f.A = 1;
f.B.alpha = 20;
f.B.beta  = 30;

ctrl = {'B.alpha', 200, 'A', 10};
for ind =1:2:length(ctrl)-1
    t=strsplit(ctrl{ind},'.');
    if length(t)==2
        f = setfield(f,t{1},t{2}, ctrl{ind+1});
    else
        f = setfield(f,ctrl{ind}, ctrl{ind+1});
    end
end
```

have a closer look to: [setfield](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html)

I'm quite sure, that there will be a better solution...  still hope that this helps :)